# Can I use a four-quadrant controller to drive a Helmholtz coil system?

Tags: power-electronics, coil, magnetics

I have a system of three Helmholtz coil pairs and need to create an arbitrarily oriented magnetic field in the center.

Since I only have a power supply that can output a positive voltage on each channel, could I use a four-quadrant controller on each power supply channel to control the polarization of the coils?

This would allow me to create an arbitrary magnetic field, instead of only covering a single octant of space, or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: What kind of power supply? Current controlled?

Comment: Draw an approximate schematic/block diagram and link data sheets to the devices you mention.

Comment: I'm not sure what a four-quadrant controller is, but if you are just creating a static field, you don't need four-quadrant ability. You do need the ability to reverse the current, using an H-bridge.

Comment: How "big" is the current needed?

Answer (score 1):

"Four-quadrant" refers to the ability of the power supply to either source or sink power while delivering either a positive or negative voltage.

Assuming that you are only trying to create a static or slow-changing magnetic field, your power supply doesn't need to absorb power. It only needs to deliver voltage (or current if you prefer) in either direction. It will always emit power, not absorb it. A circuit that can do this is the good old H-bridge.

If you suddenly flip the field polarity with the H-bridge, the coil will try to deliver power to the power supply, since the current continues in the same direction for a while. I understand that you don't need this ability - you'll adjust the current smoothly, or not at all, so the only time the polarity changes is when the current is nearly zero.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is a  bipolar voltage controlled "current" generator.
And you should know what should be the max current needed, at the chosen "speed".

So, you need to know the characteristics of your coils (resistance, inductance and capacitor parasitic values). Inductor value should be the first known).

Here is an example of such a current source (+/- 500 mA), not all checked!
Compensation circuit for inductive load ... added (C2-R7).
[image]